# Red-green dashing instead of red-white dashing

Tags: plotting

We can simply use

```
ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, 
Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.004]}, 
Directive[Red, AbsoluteDashing[{2, 3}]]}]
```

to have a plot in which one curve is dashed and another is solid. The dashed curve is colored by red and white. The color of white determines the dashing property. But how to have a curve of course a dashed curve with red and green color. I mean how green can be substituted with white for implement of dashing?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** Define a function to change the style for dashed primitives to two-colored dashing:

```
ClearAll[directive, twoColorDashing]
directive /: {directive[dirs___, dashing : (AbsoluteDashing | Dashing)[{__}], 
     cols_: {Red, Green}], l__Line} := {Directive[dirs], cols[[1]], 
   Dashing[{}], l, cols[[2]], CapForm["Butt"], dashing, l};

twoColorDashing = Module[{colors = #2}, # /. 
   Directive[a___, b : (_AbsoluteDashing | _Dashing)] :> 
     directive[a, b, First[colors = RotateRight[colors]]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
cp1 = ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, 
    Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.05], Dashing[{.05, .02}]}, 
      Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Thickness[0.03], AbsoluteDashing[{5, 3}]]}];

colors = {{Red, Yellow}, {Cyan, Purple}};

twoColorDashing[cp1, colors]
```

[image]

If `Dashing` or `AbsoluteDashing` does not appear as the last directive for a contour no change is made to the styling of that contour:

```
cp2 = ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5,  Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, 
    {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ContourStyle -> {{Black, Dashing[{.05, .02}], Thickness[0.05]}, 
     Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Thickness[0.03], AbsoluteDashing[{5, 3}]]}];

twoColorDashing[cp2, RotateRight@colors]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Another way to cheat:

```
ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, 
     Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5, 
     Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, 
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.004]}, Green,
       Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteDashing[{5, 3}]]}]
```

[image]

You can also post-process `ContourPlot` output to inject the primitives with desired style:

```
cp = ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.004]},
      Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Thick, AbsoluteDashing[{5, 3}]]}]; 

cp /. {d : Directive[__, _AbsoluteDashing], l__Line} :>
    {Thick, Green, l, d, CapForm["Butt"], l}
```

[image]

Comment: This trick had come to my mind as well but I wish to have a way without repeating a function twice. In any way thank you so much

Comment: Wonderful and intelligent!!! Fantastic

Comment: Congratulation...

Comment: Thank you @Unbelievable for the kind words and a great question.

Answer (score 2):

Overlapping two plots is the easiest:

```
cp2=ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]]==0.5,Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]]==0.5},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},ContourStyle->{{Black,Thickness[0.004]},Directive[Red,AbsoluteDashing[{2,3}]]}];
cp1=ContourPlot[Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]]==0.5,{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},ContourStyle->Green];
Show[{cp1,cp2}]
```

giving:
[image]